# AS3 Perspective View

Tags: actionscript-3, transform, perspective

I'm doing a football game which is now seen from above, I would like to know the easiest way to transform it into a perspective view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few isometric engines out there.

- [http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2010/02/23/11-flash-isomet...](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2010/02/23/11-flash-isometric-engines-you-can-use-in-your-games/)
- http://code.google.com/p/as3isolib/
- [http://www.kirupa.com/developer/actionscript/isometric_tra...](http://www.kirupa.com/developer/actionscript/isometric_transforms.htm)
  (tutorial)
- http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=136 (Can recommend this site)

What is isometric? Well google images shows alot: http://images.google.nl/search?tbm=isch&q=isometric

It is a kind of a eagle eye perspective that I think you are looking for. And you dont need a full 3d engine for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to rotate the stage and don't care about a fully isometric 3D environment, you can try playing around with the stage.rotateX stage.rotateY and stage.rotateZ properties. For a richer 3D game, you'll want to look at some of the isometric links (posted by SynerCoder) or a full 3D engine like Papervision3D (http://blog.papervision3d.org/)

Comment: I suggest Away3D, Papervision3D isn't active any more.